# VLAN setup for three Servers

Tags: cisco, vlan

As per below, i have setup a VLAN for three servers. Do you know if this is correct?

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about hosts, servers and configurations are all off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network, or on [su] for a personal network.

Answer (score 3):

No, your default gateway is wrong.  All three should be 10.20.101.4

Comment: ... or whatever else the gateway in 10.20.101.0/24 is - you can never have a (default) gateway in another subnet.

Comment: if we assign 10.20.101.4 for all server. it will be ok for us ?

Comment: how can we assign 10.20.101.4 to default gateway because we have already assigned to VLAN. i thought G/W should be 10.20.101.1 please clear on that